# Why ssh connection does not work on 22 port?

Tags: command-line, ssh, 19.10

OS Ubuntu 19.10
Hello, try connecting to DigitalOcean Droplet via SSH, but after a few minutes the command will complete without log.

```
ssh root@128.199.166.104
```

Ping is ok:

```
ping 128.199.166.104
PING 128.199.166.104 (128.199.166.104) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 128.199.166.104: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=247 ms
...
64 bytes from 128.199.166.104: icmp_seq=7 ttl=53 time=245 ms
^C
--- 128.199.166.104 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 6010ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 244.493/245.426/248.116/1.335 ms
```

Status ssh id ok:

```
systemctl status ssh
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-12-23 00:10:31 MSK; 12min ago
```

A similar issue with connecting Github via SSH to port 22 helped change the configuration.

```
cat ~/.ssh/config 
Host github.com
 Hostname ssh.github.com
 Port 443
```

What do I need to do with DigitalOcean and what is wrong with my 22 port?

Comment: Try the command `ssh -v root@128.199.166.104` and interpret its output.

Comment: Assume you will use putty for SSH session, try to follow this link to connect a droplet instance: https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/how-to/connect-with-ssh/putty/

Comment: `ssh: connect to host 128.199.166.104 port 22: Connection timed out` nothing :(

Comment: The interesting thing is that I ***can*** connect to your droplet from here: `ssh  root@128.199.166.104
root@128.199.166.104: Permission denied (publickey).
` But, of course, since I do not have your private key, I get a *permission* error. I think you have a problem in your client-side. It seems that you do not have outbound access from client or Digital Ocean is blocking access to TCP port 22 for your IP (range).